# fork() and parent/child process ids

Tags: c, linux, fork, child-process

I am a bit confused about why the child process in the following two programs is showing different parents ids.

#### First program:

```
 int main ( void ) {
   int pid, fpid, ppid;
   fpid = fork ();
   pid = getpid();
   ppid = getppid();
   printf ("fpid is %d\n", fpid);
   sleep(5);
   if (fpid > 0){
       printf ("\nThis is Parent. My pid %d. My parent's pid %d\n",pid,ppid);
   }
   else if (fpid ==0){
       sleep(1);
       printf ("\nThis is Child. My pid %d. My parent's pid %d\n",pid,ppid);
   }
   else
       printf ("fork failed\n");
   return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
fpid is 53560
fpid is 0

This is Parent. My pid 53559. My parent's pid 44632

MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/$ 

This is Child. My pid 53560. My parent's pid 53559
```

#### Second program:

```
int main ( void ) {
   int pid, fpid, ppid;
   fpid = fork ();
   printf ("fpid is is %d\n", fpid);
   sleep(5);
   if (fpid > 0){
       pid = getpid();
       ppid = getppid();
       printf ("\nThis is Parent. My pid %d. My parent's pid %d\n",pid,ppid);
   }
   else if (fpid ==0){
       sleep(1);
       pid = getpid();
       ppid = getppid();
       printf ("\nThis is Child. My pid %d. My parent's pid %d\n",pid,ppid);
   }
   else
       printf ("fork failed\n");
   return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
fpid is is 53635
fpid is is 0

This is Parent. My pid 53634. My parent's pid 44632

MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop$ 

This is Child. My pid 53635. My parent's pid 1
```

I understand that process 1 is the process that takes over as a parent once the original parent terminates.  I guess what I want to know is: isn't the parent process being finished before the child process can process its `printf` in both cases?  Shouldn't the outputs be the same?

Comment: You have a `sleep(1)` in the child, in the second program.  So, the parent would have terminated when you do `getppid()`.  That's why you are getting 1.  The first program is grabbing the ppid before sleeping and that's why you get the right value.

Comment: And in your first example you get the ppid right away, so the parent hasn't exited yet.

Comment: in general, when a parent creates a child process (for instance by calling `fork()`, the parent should ALWAYS not exit until the child has exited. This is normally accomplished by the parent calling `wait()` or `waitpid()`

Comment: process id 1 is the (in linux) the `init()` function, which runs from the very beginning until the system is shutoff or rebooted.   In modern systems, when a child's parent is exited before the child, then the `init()` process gets the child process.  However, in general, when the parent exits first, the child becomes a `zombie` process, which means it cannot be killed, deleted, etc etc. except by rebooting the computer.

Answer (score 3):

Since parent and child processes run concurrently, the order of execution depends on runtime. One of them can finish earlier. When parent finishes before child reaches its `getppid()`, child process would be adopted by `init`. Hence the parent id 1.
To see child's actual parent process id:

1. Let the parent wait for its child termination using `wait()` or `waitpid()`, or
2. Let parent sleep for some perceivable amount like `sleep(120)` after 'This is parent' `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

> isn't the parent process being finished before the child process can process it's printf in both cases?

Very likely so, but not absolutely certain.  You cannot *ensure* that by `sleep()`ing for any length of time.

> Shouldn't the outputs be the same?

They *could* be the same, but they are unlikely to be.  It's important to note when in each program `getppid()` is called.  The parent process ID reported is the one that applied at the time of the call; it is not necessarily still applicable later, when the value is printed.