# Why does the child process think the parent's process id is 1?

Tags: c, fork, posix, child-process

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void ) {
    int pid, fpid, ppid;

    fpid = fork();

    printf ("fpid is is %d\n", fpid);
    sleep(5);

    if (fpid > 0) {
        pid = getpid();
        ppid = getppid();
        printf ("\nThis is Parent. My pid %d. My parent's pid %d\n", pid, ppid);
    } else if (fpid == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        pid = getpid();
        ppid = getppid();
        printf ("\nThis is Child. My pid %d. My parent'a pid %d\n", pid, ppid);
    }
}
```

I think when the parent process ID is 1 it means that the parent process has been terminated, so the child process gets re-parented to 1 (init, the first process). Is there any reason why the parent process would be terminated?

Comment: Please format your code correctly the next time.

Comment: It has no reason to stick around, assuming a flat-out guess the remainder of your code you chose *not* to post has no `wait` in the parent process code path to wait for it's child process to finish and gather its status.

Comment: OT: `fork()` returns a `pid_t`, not an `int`, BTW. Same for `getpid()`and `getppid()`.

Comment: Your classmate already asked about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151119/fork-and-parent-child-process-ids/42151383

Answer (score 5):

Parent process doesn't wait (by means of `wait(2)`) for the child process to complete. So, if parent exits before the child (it becomes an [orphan process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process)), then child process will be re-parented (*adopted*) to *init* process whose process ID is usually 1. Thus the child process says its parent process ID is 1.

Note that the init process' ID isn't necessarily 1 on all systems. POSIX doesn't mandate any such thing.

Comment: For recent Linuxes the adopter doesn't even need to the `init` process anymore. See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519842/is-it-possible-to-adopt-a-process#comment47719364_10550076

Comment: "init" is more of conventional name (historic name from Unix days). Debians call it, for example, use systemd.

Comment: I am not referring to this. The special, quiet new thing with `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` (to be used with `prctl()`) is  is that the parent on run-time can decide which process should adopt its child ... :-)

Comment: While I wasn't referring to that, POSIX says the parent process ID of orphaned process(es) is "implementation defined system process". Which means Linux is free to do that (that you have pointed out - good info. Thanks).

Answer (score 3):

Because the child sleeps, by the time it calls `getppid()`, its parent will have likely died and the child will have been reparented to the init process (pid == 1).